# SELECT attribute names and values from XML but repeat one of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have the following XML variable:

```
DECLARE @XML1 xml
SET @XML1 = '
<updates>
  <a RowID="1" StatusTypeID="800" Name="Name800" />
  <a RowID="2" StatusTypeID="700" Name="Name700" />
  <a RowID="3" StatusTypeID="500" Name="Name500" />
</updates>'
```

I have T-SQL code that will extract the attribute names and values:

```
SELECT CAST(Attribute.Name.query('local-name(.)') AS varchar(100)) AS Attribute,
  Attribute.Name.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS Value
FROM @XML1.nodes('//@*') Attribute(Name)
```

This produces:

```
Attribute      Value
RowID          1
StatusTypeID   800
Name           Name800
RowID          2
StatusTypeID   700
Name           Name700
RowID          3
StatusTypeID   500
Name           Name500
```

How can I adjust the output so that the the RowID associated with each node is added as a separate column, i.e. the results I'd like are:

```
Attribute      Value      RowID
RowID          1          1
StatusTypeID   800        1
Name           Name800    1
RowID          2          2
StatusTypeID   700        2
Name           Name700    2
RowID          3          3
StatusTypeID   500        3
Name           Name500    3
```

Hope someone can help - thanks.

Comment: This can be solved using `pivot`. Pivot will transform the rows to the columns. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Even though I only want some of the rows transforming into a column?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not much worked with PIVOT, else would have provided you with some sample code. You may refer the documentation or google "example of pivoting using sql" to get some good examples

Comment: I've reviewed the functionality of PIVOT (also having used it briefly a while ago) and I don't believe it will allow me to solve this particular problem. Rather than pivot the results by taking a column and transforming it into row headings, I simply need an extra column adding to the existing results containing the associated RowID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution may be a little over complicated one, for your requirement, but the good part is it works.

```
DECLARE @XML1 xml
SET @XML1 = '
<updates>
  <a RowID="1" StatusTypeID="800" Name="Name800" />
  <a RowID="2" StatusTypeID="700" Name="Name700" />
  <a RowID="3" StatusTypeID="500" Name="Name500" />
</updates>'

CREATE TABLE #T 
(
 ID BIGINT Identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Attribute VARCHAR(50), Value VARCHAR(500), RowID INT
)
insert into #t (attribute,value,RowID)
SELECT CAST(Attribute.Name.query('local-name(.)') AS varchar(100)) AS Attribute,
  Attribute.Name.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS Value, 0 AS RowID
FROM @XML1.nodes('//@*') Attribute(Name)

declare @a INT
select @a = min ( value) from #t where attribute = 'RowID'
update #t
set @a = CASE WHEN attribute = 'RowID' THEN Value ELSE @a END, RowID = @a

select Attribute,Value,RowID from #t

drop table #t
```

Comment: It does indeed work, thank you - and it's not complicated at all really. I think I was trying to do too much in one single step rather than breaking it down. Thanks again.